# React-router on server always renders root route

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router, server-rendering

I've already spent half a day on this issue and can't find what is wrong. I use react-router on server. But for every route, it renders the same component (the one from root route).

Here is my server:

```
//routes
import routes from "../shared/routes";
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
    match({ routes: routes, location: request.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send(err.message)
        } else if (redirect) {
            response.status(302).redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
        } else if (props) {
            console.log('Rendering '+JSON.stringify(props));
            const appHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>);
            response.render('app', {app: appHtml});
        } else {
            response.status(404).send('Not Found')
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my routes:

```
export default (
    <Route component={AppHandler} path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={AppHandler}/>
        <Route component={AboutHandler} path="about" />
    </Route>
);
```

Other observations:

- It correctly distinguish non-existing routes, eg. when I type
  /blahblah in browser I got 404
- When I put AboutHandler as the
  component for root route, It is correctyl displayed
- I also tried "/about" as route path instead of only "about"
- Here is what I get in props `{"routes":[{"path":"/","indexRoute":{},"childRoutes":[{"path":"about"}]},{"path":"about"}],"params":{},"location":{"pathname":"/about","search":"","hash":"","action":"POP","key":"bqces8","query":{}},"components":[null,null],"router":{"location":{"pathname":"/about","search":"","hash":"","action":"POP","key":"bqces8","query":{}},"params":{},"routes":[{"path":"/","indexRoute":{},"childRoutes":[{"path":"about"}]},{"path":"about"}]},"matchContext":{"transitionManager":{},"router":{"location":{"pathname":"/about","search":"","hash":"","action":"POP","key":"bqces8","query":{}},"params":{},"routes":[{"path":"/","indexRoute":{},"childRoutes":[{"path":"about"}]},{"path":"about"}]}}}`

UPDATE:

AppHandler and AboutHandler are built using webpack. They are imported like:

```
import AppHandler from '../../build/app';
import AboutHandler from '../../build/about';
```

Here are relevant parts of both files:

app.js:

```
var App = function (_Component) {
    _inherits(App, _Component);

    function App() {
        _classCallCheck(this, App);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (App.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(App)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    _createClass(App, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {
            return _react2.default.createElement(
                'div',
                null,
                'App root'
            );
        }
    }]);

    return App;
}(_react.Component);

exports.default = App;
```

And about.js:

```
var About = function (_Component) {
    _inherits(About, _Component);

    function About() {
        _classCallCheck(this, About);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (About.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(About)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    _createClass(About, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {
            return _react2.default.createElement(
                'div',
                null,
                'About'
            );
        }
    }]);

    return About;
}(_react.Component);

exports.default = About;
```

Comment: can you post you appHandler component code

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: thanks for comment, I've added relevant parts of requested files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misundrestood nested routes in react-router and missed `{this.props.children}` in AppHandler.